# In functional programming, can a function call another function that was declared outside of it's scope and not passed as a parameter?

Tags: functional-programming

Does using a function declared outside the scope of the function it is being used in violate a Functional principle like immutability? Or is that referring specifically to data like arrays, strings, etc.

For example:

```
var data ["cat", "dog", "bird"];

function doThing (val) { 
     return val + ", go away!" 
}

function alterData (data) {
    return data.map(doThing);
}

alterData(data);
```

Would the above code be acceptable? or would the "doThing" function need to be passed into the alterData function as an argument?

The reason I am confused is because in Functional Programming examples I often see functions native to the language being used without being first passed to the function. However, the examples are never complicated enough to show how one would work with a library of functions.

Regards

Comment: I've removed the "immutability" tag because it's absolutely irrelevant.

Comment: You're right, not a good tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functional programming is no different from procedural in that regard—you write definitions that you can reuse anywhere that they are in scope.  You control what's in scope where with a variety of mechanisms, for example with module definitions, module export lists and module imports.  So for example (in Haskell):

```
module My.Module
  -- List of definitions exported from this module 
  ( doThing
  , alterData
  ) where

-- Any definitions exported from `My.Other.Module` will be in scope 
-- in this one
import My.Other.Module

-- Can't name this `data` because it's a reserved word in Haskell
yourData :: [String]
yourData = ["cat", "dog", "bird"]

doThing :: String -> String
doThing val = val ++ ", go away!" 

alterData :: [String] -> [String]
alterData strings = map doThings strings
```

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

It's fine to rely on scoping in FP code.

---

Immutability means that something represented by a name can't change its value. I wouldn't call it a "principle" of functional programming, though.

Anyway, this is not related to scoping at all. Passing things as arguments makes sense if you want to parametrize a function over another function - essentially making it a *Higher-Order function*. A good example of such is `fold` (also known as `reduce`) - but `map` is also one.

In your case `alterData` function isn't adding much value, though. `map`ping something over something is so common, that it's typically better to provide only the one-element function, as it's fundamentally more reusable.

If you've passed `doThing` to `alterData`, you'd make that function essentially useless; why would I use it, if I could simply use `map`? However, packing the operation together with the mapping can *sometimes* be an useful abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine have `doThing` the way it is.
You need to do this :

```
var data = ["cat", "dog", "bird"];

var doThing = function (val) { 
     return val + ", go away!" 
}

function alterData (data) {
    return data.map(doThing);
}

alterData(data);
```

Comment: Assuming `alterData` function is a pure function it is relying on `doThings` function to have predictable behavior. What if `doThings` function change its functionality or get removed? Then the behavior of `alterData` changes which means it is not pure. So in FP we should not rely on scoped functions and we should pass anything that function uses as its arguments.